# wordpress bad reasult with the_category

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the_category(); function in the loop but i have a problem with its result, it is displaying the category with html styling:

```
<ul class="post-categories">
<li><a href="http://localhost/wp/?cat=1" rel="category">cat name</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is make problems with W3C validator ,because using `<ul> <li>` inside the `<span>` tag wrong thing.
this is the full code:

```
<?php _e('by','junkie'); ?> <span class="meta-author"><?php the_category(); ?></span> — <span class="meta-date"><?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . _e('ago ', 'junkie'); ?></span> — <span ><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?></span>
```

so how i can get the category as `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="http://localhost/wp/?cat=1" rel="category">cat</a>
```

please help
thanks

Comment: [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$result = '';
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $cat) {
        $result .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $cat->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $cat->name ) ) . '">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>, ';
    }
echo trim($result);
}
?>
```

this will give you all the categories as  tags seperated by ", "

Answer (score 0):

thanks brother , i found a simple code to do that, it's just `<?php the_category('style=none'); ?>` and it's works good. it's give me the category without styling, `<a href="http://localhost/wp/?cat=1" rel="category">cat</a>`